# File `elocalloc.sty' not found

Tags: tikz-trees

I am trying to compile an example of the Huffmann which I found but I am getting the error:

> ! LaTeX Error: File `elocalloc.sty' not found.
>   Type X to quit or  to proceed,
>   or enter new name. (Default extension: sty)

**text**

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{forest}
\tikzset{el style/.style={midway, font=\scriptsize, inner sep=+1pt, auto=right}}
\forestset{angled/.style={
    content/.expanded={\noexpand\textless\forestov{content}\noexpand\textgreater}}}
\begin{document}
\begin{forest}
  for tree={parent anchor=south},
  where n children={0}{tier=word}{
    if={n==1}{% n == 1 means first child
      edge label={node[el style]{0}}
    }{
      edge label={node[el style, swap]{1}}
    }
  }
%
[205 [ 82 [40 [20 [10 [5 [nl, angled] ]
                      [5 [I] ] ]
                  [10 [l ] ] ]
              [20 [t ] ] ]
          [42 [20 [10 [5 [b] ]
                      [5 [d] ] ]
                  [10 [p] ] ]
              [22 [12 [5 [k] ]
                      [7 [u] ] ]
                  [10 [s ] ] ] ] ]
     [123 [53 [24 [12 [i] ]
                  [12 [o] ] ]
              [29 [l ] ] ]
          [70 [30 [15 [a] ]
                  [15 [n] ] ]
              [40 [sp, angled] ] ] ] ]
\end{forest}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Where is the sty-file? Do you have it? Where did you put it? Please put some effort in solving the issue first.

Comment: @JFMeier: I do not have this file anywhere. Please can u give a small example for creating this file?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: I ahve tried to compile several example and I am always getting this error `! LaTeX Error: File `elocalloc.sty' not found.` and not `localloc `!

Comment: localloc.sty is on ctan and should be installed if you ask miktex or texlive mapockage manager to update your system

Comment: @TheBook sorry got the name wrong, I deleted the first  comment (you can't expect me to remember the names of my own packages:-) You have updated (just) forest and so have an inconsistent installation, if you update competely or just update elocalloc in your package manager it should all work

Comment: In any case, you need to download that file because it is referenced somewhere.

Comment: @JFMeier: I am using Texmaker with MikTex 2.9. Where have I to install the `elocalloc.sty` https://www.ctan.org/pkg/elocalloc?lang=en ?

Comment: miktex will get it for you and put it in the right place, you don't need to get it from ctan "by hand" (how did you updated forest? (older versions did not use elocalloc)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: I did not know what  forest is I am using it in the example (which I found) for the first time. So I have not updated or added. Should I update it?

Comment: Please see my screen shot image.

Comment: no you _have_ an updated version:-) sorry I don't use miktex otherwise I'd tell you where its update menu is. If you want to do it by hand just put elocalloc.ins and elocalloc.dtx in the same folder as your document and run tex on elocalloc.ins and it will make elocalloc.sty but you should not have to do that. the whole point of distribution managers like miktex or texlive is that they take care of these things.

Comment: so what happens if you search for elocalloc in that package manager as shown on screen?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/32363/discussion-between-thebook-and-david-carlisle).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am using MikTex 2.9 and Texmaker. The soloution was maintenanace--> Package manager --> then the window in the screen shot is opened then enter the name elocalloc, finnlay install (The sreen shot was captured after installing thre package).

[image]

Comment: But you would be better advised to update your installation to avoid inconsistencies of this kind.

Comment: You might accept your own answer such that this question no longer shows up as unanswered.